# How To Mount RAID0 on Ubuntu (to recover data from Acer Aspire S5 Ultrabook)

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid, aspire, dmraid

Recently I ran into booting issues with windows 7 on my Acer Aspire S5 ultrabook. Before bootup, the system indicated that one of the physical disks (the ultrabook has two 128 GB SSDs in preinstalled RAID0 configuration) has problems – and on booting up windows goes into the blue screen of death mode.

I basically want to recover my data from the disks before reformatting these and reinstalling Ubuntu.

Using the USB stick, I was able to start Ubuntu (without installing it), and am able to see both these disks (and both these are showing as healthy, though with bad sectors) when viewed using 'disks'.

[image]
[image]
The output of the fdisk -l command is as follows:

```
    ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 5
Warning: invalid flag 0x3d49 of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x33fc577e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    16779263     8388608   84  OS/2 hidden C: drive
/dev/sda2        16779264    50333695    16777216   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3   *    50333696    50538495      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4        50538496   500127743   224794624    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5   ?  2025907283  4860989575  1417541146+  61  SpeedStor
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe1d9c00c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb3      3823264065  4948320604   562528270    0  Empty
```

I tried mounting the raid (which is based on Intel MATRIX Raid) by using 'dmraid -ay'

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmraid -ay
ERROR: isw: wrong number of devices in RAID set "isw_bbdaaaifgc_Aspire S5-391" [1/2] on /dev/sdb
RAID set "isw_bbdaaaifgc_Aspire S5-391" was not activated
```

Additional inputs:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmraid -r
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_bbdaaaifgc", GROUP, ok, 250069678 sectors, data@ 0
```

How do I get the disks to mount in the original RAID0 configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get the disks to mount in RAID0 any more when one of the disks fails...  RAID0 is basically a striping set and when one of the disks fails, the entire RAID array fails and the [fat lady *has sung*...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_ain%27t_over_till_the_fat_lady_sings)

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news!*  **:-(**

The only thing you can do now is reformat (or replace) and [restore your back-up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)...